# Python 2.7 - weird behaviour on finally clause

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, raspberry-pi

I've run into a very strange problem, that is making me wonder if I understand exception handling at all.

I have a code (that I'll post at the end) that looks more or less like this:

```
try:
    doSomething()
finally:
    print 'bye'
```

The code in the finally clause is not being executed when I exit my program via ctrl+c.

To make matters worse, now consider the following:

```
try:
    doSomething()
except:  # this could be replaced by except Exception, it doesn't matter
    print 'something'
finally:
    print 'bye'
```

Now the code in the except clause is not executed.. but the code in the finally clause is!

I realize this has to be the fault of the code executed by doSomething(). But my question is, how is it even possible? I thought we could be 100% confident that finally clauses always got executed.

Here goes the real code. It's running on a raspberry pi 3. It's an adaptation of the code found [here](http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2012/08/reading-analogue-sensors-with-one-gpio-pin/).

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO, time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

# Define function to measure charge time
def RCtime (PiPin):
    # Discharge capacitor
    GPIO.setup(PiPin, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(PiPin, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(.1)

    time1 = time.time()
    GPIO.setup(PiPin, GPIO.IN)
    if (GPIO.input(PiPin) == GPIO.LOW):
        GPIO.wait_for_edge(PiPin, GPIO.RISING, timeout=1000)
    time_elap = time.time()-time1

    return time_elap*1e3

# Main program loop
try:
    while True:
        print RCtime(4) # Measure timing using GPIO4
except Exception:
    print '---------got ya-----------------'
finally:
    print '---Finaly---'
    GPIO.cleanup() # this ensures a clean exit
```

To be more specific, the behaviour depicted appears when the program is waiting at the `GPIO.wait_for_edge(PiPin, GPIO.RISING, timeout=1000)` line.

Comment: Except will only be executed if try fails. finally will be done if try finishes or fails as long as the program is still running. Crtl-c is the same as sys.exit(). An exception would be thrown but the program terminates, there is no way to handle that exception because python quits.

Comment: @TheLazyScripter Ctrl-C produces [**`KeyboardInterrupt`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.KeyboardInterrupt) which can be caught in an exception block (but not by `except Exception` as `KeyboardInterrupt` inherits from [`BaseException`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.BaseException) and not `Exception`

Comment: The point isn't whether I catch the exception or not. The point is that the program is terminating and the finally block is not being executed (in the first case). I'm asking how this is even possible.

Answer (score 1):

If your code does not handle the `KeyboardInterrupt` exception, the system has to do it: which means it kills the code. Instead, if you have an exception handler, your code takes over, leaves the loop and then executes the `finally` block.

Comment: The point isn't whether I catch the exception or not. The point is that the program is terminating and the finally block is not being executed (in the first case). I'm asking how this is even possible.

Comment: Since you don't catch the exception, the OS terminates your program immediately. So there is no chance to execute the `finally` block. If you caught the exception, whether you do anything with it or not - you've prevented the OS from killing your code, so it can continue to the final part.

Comment: That's not how it works @VBB. Finally is supposed to always be executed. Try this python snippet:
`try:
    1/0
finally:
     print 'Im here anyway'
`

Answer (score 0):

Well, this seems to be a bug related to the way RPi.GPIO handles signals (such as KeyboardInterrupt). This module invokes some functions written in c. The function is sort of catching the KeyboardInterrupt and throwing an exception, but it doesn't do it properly. Instead of getting only one exception, the two exceptions get "stacked". Because of that, the first thing that run after an exception in my code is going to be terminated by the second exception. If I don't include an except block, the finally block gets executed after the first exception, and is terminated by the second exception. If I include an except block, it tries to run after the first exception, it fails because of the second exception, and then it goes to the finally block.
I only found one [forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.python/raOemE38PaY%20) where people deal with a similar problem.

> After my previous experiment I was curious how this works with
>   input() [https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Parser/myreadline.c]. I replaced the sem.acquire() with raw_input() and ran the same
>   tests. Now the inner exception is really taken so it works like the OP
>   expected. The exception, however is KeyboardInterrupt, not the special
>   exception from the IPC module.
>   So I looked in the source code how they did it: 
>   The code is in Parser/myreadline.c.
>
> This code for input in function calls PyErr_CheckSignals() and
>   PyOS_InterruptOccurred() for a proper handling of the interrupt. So it
>   seems the OP should do something similar. Onl;y to deliver the custom
>   error you will have to do some other stuff. I don't know what but maybe
>   calling PyErr_SetString is sufficient as it might overwrite the
>   KeyboardInterrupt stuff.